# conditional data annotation asp.net MVC

Tags: validation

I have a class having properties with properties:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide client name")]
    public string externalClientName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide client email")]
    public string externalClientEmail { get; set; }
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public string typeOfClient { get; set; }
```

Its running fine for the view and the validation are showing perfectly but is there any way out to

make this conditional,I mean in my view certain conditons runs which sometimes want "externalClientEmail" mandatory and sometimes not.

PLease suggest some action

Comment: Hi do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MVC fool proof validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) to achieve this, add the DLL , then `using Foolproof;`

add a boolean property to you model

```
public bool isExternalClientEmailRequired { get; set; }
```

then decorate `externalClientEmail` with the RequiredIf attribute.

```
[RequiredIf("isExternalClientEmailRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "Please provide client email")]
public string externalClientEmail { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you please bit elaborate how to put this bool in view and enable/disable the validation

Comment: In which condition would you like the externalClientEmail to be required, add a little more details to your post